# Formula for selecting/ordering cell from given box

Tags: excel

Let's say have a box 10x10 of cells.
Some cells might be empty.

Is there a way to select consecutive non-empty cells?
Starting from top left moving to right, then moving to next row.
So that I could create same box but with no gaps?

```
xx_xxxx__x    xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxx_xxxx    xxxxxxxxxx
xx__xxxxxx    xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx_    xxx_______
```

Is there a way to do this via formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going off your example, assuming the data is in cell range `A1:J4`, paste this formula into a cell and drag over 10 rows and down 4 columns:

```
= IF(COLUMNS($A$1:$J$4)*(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)+COLUMNS($A$1:A1)<=COUNTA($A$1:$J$4),"x","")
```

See below. In this example, I pasted this formula into cell `L1`.

[image]

Note also that this formula works for variable sized ranges, doesn't just have to be 4x10.

Comment: Big thanks, that is definitely beyond my casual excel skill.

Comment: No problem. Unique question. I enjoyed figuring out that one haha.